# JPA Hibernate working very slow

Tags: performance, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I am learning JPA.
I tried the Spring-JPA-Hibernate combination. 
The application works and I get the results.
But though there is only 1 record in the database, it is taking about 4 to 5 minutes to load the page.
Not quite sure what I am doing wrong.
I Googled for the same but all I am getting are performance optimization suggestions but I think I am missing something more basic as there is only 1 record in my table.

Here are the details:

**Persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
  <persistence-unit name="bike_unit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
  <jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/testdb123</jta-data-source>
    <class>bike.Bike</class>
    <class>bike.Company</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/bike"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="abc"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="abc"/>
    </properties>

  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>bikeDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>bikeDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/home.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <resource-env-ref>
        <resource-env-ref-name>jdbc/testdb123</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>javax.sql.DataSource</resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>

</web-app>
```

**context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
<Resource name="jdbc/testdb123" auth="Container" 
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    username="abc" password="abc" 
    driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" 
    url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/bike" />
</Context>
```

I am using Spring 3 and Hibernate 3 jar files.
I tried replacing Hibernate with Eclipselink and the applications works perfect. Its only when I use JPA with Hibernate that I have slowness issues.

Here are the jars I used with Eclipselink and Hibernate:

Eclipselink:

- eclipselink.jar
- javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar
- javax.persistence.source_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar

Hibernate:

- ejb3-persistence.jar
- hibernate-annotations.jar
- hibernate-commons-annotations.jar

With Eclipselink, this is how my persistance.xml looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
  <persistence-unit name="bike_unit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>bike.Bike</class>
    <class>bike.Company</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/bike" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="abc" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="abc" />
    </properties>

  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: It's difficult to suggest what could be the exact reason, however I would suggest to enable hibernate logging and see if you can find some clue. Also worth using would be VisualVM.

Comment: Realized that it is the Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME) method that is consuming all the time. Thanks @Shailendra for giving me a direction to look.

Comment: Glad to help ! Typically for a web application, the entity manager factory would be created once for each database and each individual request would their own entity manager instances.

Answer (score 0):

I had this performance problem on Windows 7 Desktop.
However, I did not face this issue when tried on a Windows 8 Machine with identical code and database.

Did not find the root cause but solved my problem for now.